# How to search in a sticky header FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, search

I implemented a FlatList with sticky header which fetches data from `Content.json`.

[image: flatlist with sticky header]

But when I implemented search functionality, got the following error.

[image: error after implementing search functionality]

Here's the link to the code.
https://snack.expo.io/@cmcodes/anxious-toffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding what you were trying to achieve, you should have:

```js
<FlatList
  data={filteredContent}
  renderItem={this.renderContent}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
  stickyHeaderIndices={this.state.stickyHeaderIndices}
/>
```

And then, in your `renderContent`:

```js
  renderContent = ({ item }) => {
    const content = item
    if (content.header) {
      return (
        <ListItem itemDivider>
          <Body>
            <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>{content.name}</Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      );
    } else if (!content.header) {
      return (
        <ListItem style={{marginLeft: 0}}>
          <Body>
            <Text>{content.name}</Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      );
    }
  };
```

Remember that the function `renderItem` gives you an `item` inside an object, and it has that name, so you can't just use it as `content`.

EDIT: https://snack.expo.io/ga7o0KyZX

Comment: I got your point! But, it didn't worked! I need search functionality! If the user types "Television" in the search bar, then ONLY "Television" should be displayed in the FlatList. You can try editing the code in the snack link above.

Comment: I just did, this example works. Replace these parts in your snack and it should work.

Comment: @cmcodes Here ya go: https://snack.expo.io/ga7o0KyZX

Comment: You are running it on "Web" emulator in Snack. Change it to "Android" and you will see the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'search.toLowerCase')`

Comment: Here's the link to the working code of searching in a FlatList with sticky headers.

https://snack.expo.io/@cmcodes/forlorn-cake